# Node-red line chart is not working as I want

Tags: python, mqtt, node-red

I am new to node red. I have a code that publish and one for subscribe

Publish

```
import time
import paho.mqtt.client as paho
import random

broker = 'broker.emqx.io'
device_id = 'sensoras_kouzina_123458'

# Function to connect to the MQTT broker
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc == 0:
        print("Connected to MQTT broker")
    else:
        print("Connection failed")

# Create MQTT client instance
client = paho.Client('client-001')
client.on_connect = on_connect

# Connect to the MQTT broker
print('Connecting to broker:', broker)
client.connect(broker)

# Start the MQTT network loop
client.loop_start()

try:
    while True:
        # Generate random temperature and HVAC status
        temperature = random.randint(0, 60)
        hvac_status = random.choice(["On", "Off"])
        
        # Create the message payload
        message = { 
            "id": device_id,
            "temperature": temperature,
            "status": hvac_status
        }

        # Publish the message to the MQTT broker
        print('Publishing:', message)
        client.publish('Test/Temperature', str(message))

        time.sleep(8)  # Wait for 8 seconds before publishing the next message

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # Stop the MQTT network loop
    client.loop_stop()

    # Disconnect from the MQTT broker
    client.disconnect()
```

Subscribe

```
# Import modules

import paho.mqtt.client as mymqtt
import time

# Subscribe to temperature sensor data generated by server
mqtt_topic = 'Test/Temperature'
mqtt_server = 'test.mosquitto.org'

# Subscribe to data published by publisher.py
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print('Connected with result '+ str(rc))
    client.subscribe(mqtt_topic)

# Display data published
def on_message(client1, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic +' '+ str(msg.payload))
    print()

client = mymqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect(mqtt_server,1883)
client.loop_start()

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(2)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # End infinite loop using Ctrl+C in command prompt
    client.loop_stop()
    client.disconnect()
```

I want a linear chart that displays only the temperature not hvac_status and not device id

```
msg.topic = 'Test/Temperature'
return msg
```

Doing that is sawing me Y axis values from 1,687,356,836,600 to 1,687,356,837,800 and X axis the time.
Why I see so big numbers?

I want Y axis display 0-60 Cesium and X axis time in seconds or minutes

Comment: Remove the subscriber code from the question (since nr is the subscriber this tells nothing useful), then add a debug node to the MQTT-in node and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34603390) in the output so we can see exactly what you are feeding to the chart node

Comment: This video https://youtu.be/4QjrpaHy1YA?t=29 shows the debug node working.